# Calling external Libraries in Wordpress

Tags: themes, jquery, css

I am doing some maintenance on a blog that I was hired to create a couple of months ago. They wanted to add a slider in, so I started to implement FlexSlider. I ran into a problem though with the slider.

I have added the needed dependencies into the header:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

In my index file, I have:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="flexslider">

        <ul class="slides">         
            <li>
   <?php query_posts(array ( 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'tag'=> 'one' )); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php       $slider_image = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'slider_image', true);?>
<img src="<?php echo $slider_image[0]['image']; ?>" />      


        <div class="info">
        <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> <?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
            <p><?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author() ?></p>

                <p><?php echo excerpt(55); ?></p>
                <p class="read"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"> Read More ></a></p>
        <?php endwhile; ?> 
   </div>
    </li>






        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

My issue is this really, when you look at the slider, the "slides" dont seem to be styled at all, and the jquery files do not seem to be functioning at all. I keep seeing an error that:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'slides'
:1112/:22Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'flexslider'
```

You can see what I am working on at http://louisstephens.cc/blog (using my own blog so I do not mess up the client's site). Does anyone see something that I am missing to get this functioning properly?

Comment: Are you running a child theme? If so, you'll need to replace the `get_bloginfo('template_directory')` calls with `get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory')`. There's also no need to load jquery, just set that as a dependancy when you [enqueue](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) flexslider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your functions.php add this code

```
function load_custom_script() {

    wp_deregister_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js', false, '1.6.2');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script('jquery.flexslider', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery.flexslider');

}

function load_custom_style() {
    wp_register_style('flexslider', get_bloginfo('template_url').'/flexslider.css', array(), '');
    wp_enqueue_style('flexslider');
}

add_action('wp_print_scripts', 'load_custom_script');
add_action('wp_print_styles', 'load_custom_style');
```

Do not forget to remove your code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for the help. I did find that the blank theme I use to build off on registers an older version of jquery in my functions.php file. So when I was calling a newer version of jquery in my header.php file (with the other slider dependencies), it was conflicting with the older version that was being called in wp_head and wp_footer. I actually stumbled across it once @Bouchaala Sabri advised me to put his block of code into the functions.php file.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `jQuery` instead of the shorthand `$`.

Also you should `wp_enqueue_script` to insert jQuery and the FlexSlider script. 
 You can find a good tutorial on that [here](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-the-enqueue-script-for-wordpress-themes-and-plugins/).

Comment: Should using the enqueue solve the issue?

Comment: Using `jQuery` instead of `$` should solve the issue. But `wp_enqueue_script` is the prescribed way to link to scripts.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't think I understand you completely.. Where am I replacing the cash sign? I the one in the main file is being used in php.